# How to confirm source was correctly installed

Tags: linux, installation, unix, aix

I've installed CFEngine from source (for those of you who aren't familiar with the product, check out the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfengine)) on an AIX server. I had some issues setting it up but finally got it to `gmake` successfully.

Once I run `gmake install` I get a very short output (based on other source builds) and no errors. I figure something is fishy and I now I need to figure out a good way to find if it was correctly installed. I tried:

```
find / -name cfeng* 2> /dev/null
```

Is there something analogous to `rpm -qa | grep cfengine`?

Here is a copy of my output in case anyone needs: http://pastebin.com/tCFZTk22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `gmake install` script puts the binary in a standard location, `which cfengine` should tell you the location of the (default) binary.

From what you wrote ... did you `install` before you just ran `make`? You have to compile the software before installing it in most cases. The cycle is usually `make` then `make install`.

Comment: Sorry if it seems like I didn't make first, but I did. I configured, then compiled then installed. Installation is where the issue occurs.

Comment: I looked at the output a little more carefully and checked /usr/local/sbin and found the executables I was looking for. I guess it did install correctly. However, is this the only way to look for confirmation of installation?

Comment: The thing is, there is no standard for `make install` that tells the developer to confirm anything. Some scripts do echo a success message to the standard output, but others (apparently including cfengine) do not.